# Django Rest Set some new value on django view on Post

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My form will post data to db.

I want to add one filed as hidden in view and it should generate a key as random.

my post function is

```
        def post(self, request, format=None):
            request.data['code'] = id_generator()
            data = request.data
            serializer = registrationform(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                x=serializer.data
                data = { "ack":"success"}
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

here the id_generator() will genrate some random values.

In the serializer

```
class regiform(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    code = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)

    class  Meta:
        fields = ( 'mobile', 'profile_image', 'code')
        model = registration
```

so now the code filed is not showing in API view , but submitting the form by post the code is still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting as only read and docs says that it will not be able to be used to set values:

> Set this to True to ensure that the field is used when serializing a representation, but is not used when creating or updating an instance during deserialization.

So if you want to do it hidden you can use in CharField the style tag allowed like: `serializers.CharField(style={'input_type':'hidden'})`

Advice: You should Use HiddenField instead of CharField as HiddenField takes the value from a callable or default value that it seems that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Actually this line

```
request.data['code'] = id_generator()
```

will not update your request.data. You wrote this line by assuming that request.data is a dictionary and it will update your dict with new field code. Fact is that request.data is QueryDict. check it by

```
print type(request.data)
```

It does not update new field that way.

For achieving what you want , you can transfer your 'code' field generation to serializer in following way.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
            serializer = registrationform(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                x=serializer.data
                data = { "ack":"success"}
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

in the serializer

```
class regiform(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     code = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

     class  Meta:

          fields = ( 'mobile', 'profile_image',)
          model = registration

     def get_code(self, obj):
          return id_generator()
```